# SVG image scale? For mobile applicatios

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-mobile, svg, cross-browser

I read a lot of resources, but I can't seem to get SVG images to fit in the browser window.

I was told that if I have to use images in Mobile applications that fit in the modern mobile browsers, I have to use SVG images in html5 pages.

I can't seem to get the SVG image to work! 
I'm saving it from illustrator, then embedding in html5 page with 100% width div.

What's the best method for doing this?
Thanks for any help..

By the way, i'm using Jquery mobile/HTML5/CSS3

```
<embed src="header.svg" type="image/svg+xml" codebase="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install" />
```

How should i specify a certain width and height in "viewBox" when i want it to fit to the device size? i dont have a specific size

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Basic//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-basic.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="Layer_1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="253px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 253 60" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <defs>............
```

Comment: Can you add the source code of one of your SVG images to the question?  Or link to it?

Comment: By the way, i tried to upload the page with the image, and it does not show online?!!

Comment: Your SVG has its internal metric system, which is used for all positions and sizes of its internal objects. You specify the "view box" over your SVG, which will be scaled when displaying SVG in browser. Just try some values and play with it a little.

Comment: Open the SVG file in notepad, copy and paste the text you see into your question, select that text and click on the format as code tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your audience is using a browser with an HTML 5 parser ([now widely supported](http://caniuse.com/svg-html5)) you don't need any of the xml stuff directly in an svg tag. You don't need an object or embed tag tag. That's old school at this point. And you *certainly* don't need an iFrame. Also , just to clarify, SVG has nothing to do with jQuery, per se (in fact jquery plays quite badly with svg elements). Just make sure you're using the html5 doctype, and write it something like this:

```
<svg id="mycoolgraphic" viewBox="0 0 253 60" >
<g>
    <g>
        <defs>............
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Make sure all your tags are closed, and valid as xml. Don't tab indent or add a whole bunch of spacing, that will only create empty text nodes. Just leave it all ugly and smushed together. It makes any javascript work much easier later on. If you're using illustrator (which is just fine) you will probably want to go in and clean some of the xml declarations out of the main svg tag. Omit any explicit height and width if you want the element to be responsive. You can control height and width via ordinary CSS declarations:

```
   #mycoolgraphic { height: 10em;width: 10em;}
```

The main trick in doing responsive svg is setting the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. This is something you'll need to add. (Graphics exported from Illustrator won't include anything for `preserveAspectRatio`.) This attribute controls how svg content (the *viewbox*) is scaled within the svg element (the svg *viewport*). The viewbox is proportionally fixed. It was the bounding rectangle when you created the art in illustrator. Don't mess with it unless you're very sure you know what you're doing. The svg element that contains the viewbox, however, can be sized like any html element, and the preserveAspectRatio attribute describes the relationship between the two. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) article on preserveAspectRatio is good. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) is also surprisingly readable on this point.

Hope this helps!